# How to get the unmatched element from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array and suppose it is `$resultSet`.

Now, I would like to get all the other elements **which are not matching to a particular key.**

In order to make a simple array search I can use `$key = array_search(40489, array_column($resultSet, 'playerId'));` but that would give me the matched set but I require the unmatched set. How can I do it in simplest way other than making a function for it?

**In detail**
Suppose the following is the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 33
            [playerId] => 17875
            [room] => e3724021
            [playerName] => Lunch
            [boardSize] => 4
            [lastPing] => 1488089513
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 34
            [playerId] => 22072
            [room] => e3724021
            [playerName] => Dinner
            [boardSize] => 4
            [lastPing] => 1488089536
        )

)
```

Now suppose am searching for the array with the `playerId: 17875`, then I should get back the whole array which has the `[playerId] => 22072`.

Comment: try `array_diff()` function

Comment: I am not comparing two arrays for difference.

Comment: can you please show me the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter using `array_filter` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Example using it as a function.

```
<?php 

$resultSet = array(
  array("id" => 33,
        "playerId" => 17875,
        "room" => "e3724021",
        "playerName" => "Lunch",
        "boardSize" => 4,
        "lastPing" => 1488089513),
  array("id" => 34,
      "playerId" => 22072,
      "room" => "e3724021",
      "playerName" => "Dinner",
      "boardSize" => 4,
      "lastPing" => 1488089536)
);

function filterOut($arr, $key, $value) {
  return array_filter($arr, function ($v) use ($key,$value) {
    return $v[$key] !== $value;
  });
}


print_r(filterOut($resultSet, 'playerId', 17875));

// Array
// (
//     [1] => Array
//         (
//             [id] => 34
//             [playerId] => 22072
//             [room] => e3724021
//             [playerName] => Dinner
//             [boardSize] => 4
//             [lastPing] => 1488089536
//         )

// )
```

Comment: I am getting `undefined variable` for `$value` on line `return $v !== $value;` in my IDE.

Comment: Forgot to bind `$value` to the closure. See the update

Comment: Umm, somethings not right. I get warnings `Missing argument 2 for game::{closure}()...` and the array returned is just `Array ( [1] => 22072 ) ` whereas I need the whole array belonging to key 1

Comment: If you want the full array then there is no need for `array_column`. I have edidted to include a full working example